# Al hacer una consulta me aparece el numero 1 en el input - PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Mi problema es el siguiente, al hacer una consulta me aparece el numero 1 en el input automáticamente, alguien sabe por que?.

Adjunto imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí les dejo el Código - PHP

```
   <?php
   include 'conexion.php';
   ?>

  <form action="buscador.php" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="palabra" placeholder="buscar aqui.." value="<?php  
  echo(isset($_POST["palabra"])); ?>" oNclick="this.value=''"; />
 <input type="submit" name="buscador" value="Buscar" id="buscar" />
   <style type="text/css">
   #buscar{
    display: none;
  }

 </style>
 </form>

 <?php 

 if(isset($_POST['buscador'])){

 $buscar = $_POST['palabra'];

 if (empty($buscar)){
echo "No se ha ingresado ninguna palabra";
 }
else
{

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM peliculas WHERE nombre LIKE '%$buscar%'";
 $result = $conexion->query($sql);

 $total = mysqli_num_rows($result);

 if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

  echo "Resultados para: $buscar";
  ?>
 <br>
<?php

do {
 ?>
 <br>
 <br>
  <a href="<?php echo $row['link'] ?>">(nombre: <?php echo $row['nombre']; ?>)</a>

<?php
}
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result));
 }
else
 {
 echo "No se encontraron resultados para: $buscar";
 }
 }
 }
?>
```

Comment: Deberías ver bien cómo concatenar valores en php. Pero aparte de eso, esto está gritando "SQL Injection"

Comment: Aquí estas cerrando las comillas antes de hora: `value="<?php  
  echo(isset($_POST["palabra"])); ?>"`. Deberías de usar comillas simples en su lugar para sacar la palabra: `value="<?php  
  echo(isset($_POST['palabra'])); ?>"`

Comment: @Lamak con esto evitaría SQL injection? mysqli_real_escape_string.
no se mucho de seguridad pero estoy investigando.

Comment: @kyle [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/127)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problema:**

```
echo(isset($_POST["palabra"]))
```

devuelve true, que se imprime como 1.

Solución:

```
echo(isset($_POST["palabra"]) ? $_POST["palabra"]:'');
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias! :)